# Apache Flink with S3 Minio state backend - Cannot run the job locally from IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: apache-flink, minio

Is it possible to run an Apache Flink job with a S3 state backend locally from a development environment?
The IDE I'm using is IntelliJ IDEA.

I created the project from the following Maven archetype:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-quickstart-scala</artifactId>
    <version>1.14.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The Scala implementation looks like the following:

```scala
val configuration = new org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration

val accessKey = "minio"
val secretKey = "minioSecret"

configuration.setString("state.backend", "filesystem")

val scheme = "s3p://"
val checkpointDirectory = "org-flink/sp"

configuration.setString("state.checkpoints.dir", scheme + checkpointDirectory)
configuration.setString("state.backend.fs.checkpointdir", scheme + checkpointDirectory)

configuration.setString("presto.s3.endpoint", "http://192.168.1.51")
configuration.setString("presto.s3.path-style-access:", "true")
configuration.setString("presto.s3.access-key", accessKey)
configuration.setString("presto.s3.secret-key", secretKey)

val env = org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment(configuration)

env.enableCheckpointing(10000, CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE)

//...
```

I also tried to include a META-INF/services/org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystemFactory file with the following content:

```
org.apache.flink.fs.s3presto.S3PFileSystemFactory
```

I verified the end point with minio client:

```
mc alias set minio http://192.168.1.51 minio minioSecret

mc ls minio

mc mb minio/org-flink/sp
```

In the documentation for [Amazon S3](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/filesystems/s3/#hadooppresto-s3-file-systems-plugins) it is written that it is easy to setup the plugins.

In a docker file it can be achieved in the following way:

```
mkdir ./plugins/s3-fs-presto
cp ./opt/flink-s3-fs-presto-1.14.2.jar ./plugins/s3-fs-presto/
```

How can I achieve the same from IntelliJ IDEA? I tried to copy the `flink-s3-fs-presto-1.14.2.jar` under the projects target subfolder target\plugins\s3-fs-presto . I suppose this should be done differently, but I have no idea where to put this jar. Is it possible to define it in a Maven pom.xml file?

I'm getting the following **exception**:

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException: Failed to create checkpoint storage at checkpoint coordinator side.
at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator.<init>(CheckpointCoordinator.java:328)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator.<init>(CheckpointCoordinator.java:244)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.DefaultExecutionGraph.enableCheckpointing(DefaultExecutionGraph.java:452)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.DefaultExecutionGraphBuilder.buildGraph(DefaultExecutionGraphBuilder.java:315)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultExecutionGraphFactory.createAndRestoreExecutionGraph(DefaultExecutionGraphFactory.java:107)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.createAndRestoreExecutionGraph(SchedulerBase.java:334)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.<init>(SchedulerBase.java:190)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.<init>(DefaultScheduler.java:130)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultSchedulerFactory.createInstance(DefaultSchedulerFactory.java:132)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.DefaultSlotPoolServiceSchedulerFactory.createScheduler(DefaultSlotPoolServiceSchedulerFactory.java:110)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.createScheduler(JobMaster.java:346)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.<init>(JobMaster.java:323)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.factories.DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.internalCreateJobMasterService(DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.java:106)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.factories.DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.lambda$createJobMasterService$0(DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.java:94)
at org.apache.flink.util.function.FunctionUtils.lambda$uncheckedSupplier$4(FunctionUtils.java:112)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.core.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemSchemeException: Could not find a file system implementation for scheme 's3p'. The scheme is directly supported by Flink through the following plugin: flink-s3-fs-presto. Please ensure that each plugin resides within its own subfolder within the plugins directory. See https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/plugins.html for more information. If you want to use a Hadoop file system for that scheme, please add the scheme to the configuration fs.allowed-fallback-filesystems. For a full list of supported file systems, please see https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/filesystems/.
at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.getUnguardedFileSystem(FileSystem.java:515)
at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:409)
at org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:274)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsCheckpointStorageAccess.<init>(FsCheckpointStorageAccess.java:64)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.storage.FileSystemCheckpointStorage.createCheckpointStorage(FileSystemCheckpointStorage.java:323)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator.<init>(CheckpointCoordinator.java:325)
... 18 more
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you should add the dependency of `flink-s3-fs-presto` or `flink-s3-fs-hadoop`